# Another question on linearly lindelöf space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be first countable and linearly lindelöf.

> **Condition:** If $A$ is uncountable subset of $X$, and there exists a family $\{U_a: a \in A\}$ of disjoint open sets of $X$ such that $a \in U_a$.

Would this condition be a contradiction with $X$ being first countable and linearly lindelöf? In other words, can the space $X$ allow such subset $A$ exist?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: So basically you are asking whether a first countable linearly Lindelöf space is ccc?

Comment: @Henno: Yes, it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So basically you are asking whether a first countable linearly Lindelöf space is ccc? 
(such an $A$ exists of course iff there is an uncountable collection of non-empty open pairwise disjoint subsets iff $X$ is not ccc)

The lexicographically ordered square is a compact counterexample. There $A = I \times \{\frac{1}{2}\}$ is such an uncountable family. And $X$ is compact (so trivially linearly Lindelöf).